# jsPlumb not adding EndPoints correctly when the div is animated

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

jsPlumb seems to incorrectly place the EndPoints when the node div is animated.  The endpoints are placed (initially) at [0,0] and not  connected to the moving div.

When the div is dragged, then the end points get updated and attah to the divs correctly.  The problem is demostrated in this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/rishabhsagar/aT63t/27/

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because jsPlumb is not expecting the third argument to be a string; it's expecting an object.

try this fiddle instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/sporritt/QpLJU/10/

i just replaced "slow" with {duration:"slow"}.

Comment: Thanks!  Although I worked around at the time I posted the problem, I am going to go back in change the code in my hobby app!